# Как найти в строке только определенное слово "cat"? JS

Tags: javascript

"exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category" - есть строка и допустим в ней появится слово "cat" ("exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat") как найти именно это слово? Ещё может быть такое ("exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat pet") - это не подходит, нужно чтобы находило конкретно слово "cat"

Comment: Найти чтобы что? Чтобы выделить как-то? Или найти позицю вхождения? Или цель узнать есть ли слово в строке? Или что?

Comment: @СергейМишин Салам , ты в jQuery силён ?

Comment: Цель узнать есть ли это слово в строке, чтобы потом вывести нужный мне элемент массива.

Comment: @AlexandrStupak используй `includes()` / Пример `"exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat pet".includes('cat')`  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @СергейМишин почему toggleClass не работает ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/gOYgOGr

Comment: "exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat pet".includes('cat') будет true, но если есть такое "cat pet и т.д" то это не подходит

Comment: @AlexandrStupak всё подходит https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg8wb.png

Comment: @СергейМишин В таком случает должно быть false, "cat pet" === false, "cat" === true

Comment: @AlexandrStupak ты сам написал "Цель узнать есть ли это слово в строке". Что это за манипуляции: "cat pet" === false, "cat" === true  ??? Где здесь `includes`??

Comment: @СергейМишин сорри что вначале не сказал за это :(

Comment: @AlexandrStupak в общем я не понял что надо. Для задачи  "Цель узнать есть ли это слово в строке" есть https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes. Если что-то надо другое - надо писать в вопросе что и зачем. Иначе начинается гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: @СергейМишин https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1016240/308951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str = 'cat pet, cat, category';
const entries = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);
const indexOfCat = entries.indexOf('cat');
console.log(indexOfCat); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое что можно сделать.

`findIndex()` возвращает индекс конкретного искомого элемента.

```js
const array = ['exam', 'scientific experiment', 'computer icon', 'category', 'cat']

const result = array.findIndex(element => element === 'cat')

console.log(result)
```

или же если нужен элемент

```js
const array = ['exam', 'scientific experiment', 'computer icon', 'category', 'cat']

const result = array.find(element => element === 'cat')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: indexOf не подходит потому что он показывает индекс category

Comment: @alexandr-stupak так надо указывать, что вам нужен индекс именно

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @alexandr-stupak https://tproger.ru/translations/javascript-arrays-best-practices/  почитай про массивы

Comment: @alexandr-stupak и нумерация массива начинается с нуля, `indexOf не подходит потому что он показывает индекс category` все правильно выводит  `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

**Метод 1 (если в строке строго идут слова/выражения через запятую)**

```
let str = "exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat"; //исходная строка
let words = str.split(',').map(word=>word.trim()); //Создаем массив слов, пробелы по бокам каждого слова обрезаются.
let answer = words.includes('cat'); //true/false
```

**Метод 2 (регулярное выражение)**

```
let str = "exam, scientific experiment, computer icon, category, cat";
let regexp = /,\s*cat\s*$/i; /*Выражение ищет запятую, обрезает пробельные символы и определяет, есть ли еще слова. /i значит не учитывать регистр, можно убрать */
let answer = regexp.test(str); // вернет true/false
let answer2 = str.match(regexp); // вернет null, если нет совпадения либо массив со свойством index - позиция найденного слова в строке
```

Comment: Ух, метод 1 - убойный. А чем `includes` от строкового объекта не устраивает?

Comment: тем что он найдет "cat" в category и в cat pet ?