# Почему не срабатывает toggleClass в моем случае?

Tags: jquery

Имеется меню но надо что бы работало как и по кнопке так и закрывалось вне блока , блок вне элемента закрывается **но не работает toggleClass.**

> Что надо сделать с ним что бы  работал и toggleClass и была
>   возможность закрыть блок вне его ..?

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  //$(".menu").addClass("show");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".show");
  if (!container.is(e.target) &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.removeClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  position: absolute;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="">.item1</a>
  <a href="">.item2</a>
  <a href="">.item3</a>
  <a href="">.item4</a>
  <a href="">.item5</a>
  <a href="">.item6</a>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  button
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код прекрасно работает, при клике вне контейнера он закрывается, при клике по кнопке - отображается +) что не так то?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков toggleClass не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  //$(".menu").addClass("show");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".show");
  if (!container.is(e.target) &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0 &&
    !$(e.target).hasClass("btn")) {
    container.removeClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  position: absolute;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="">.item1</a>
  <a href="">.item2</a>
  <a href="">.item3</a>
  <a href="">.item4</a>
  <a href="">.item5</a>
  <a href="">.item6</a>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  button
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что порядок срабатывания событий `mousedown` -> `mouseup` -> `click`

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
  console.log('toggle');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".show");
  if (
    !container.is(e.target) &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0
  ) {
    container.removeClass("show");
    console.log('remove');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  position: absolute;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="">.item1</a>
  <a href="">.item2</a>
  <a href="">.item3</a>
  <a href="">.item4</a>
  <a href="">.item5</a>
  <a href="">.item6</a>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  button
</div>
```

Когда вы кликаете по кнопке первый раз, вначале срабатывает `$(document).mouseup()` но здесь `container = $(".show");` ничего не находится и процедура не выполняется. Затем срабатывает `$(".btn").on("click")` и вешается класс

При втором клике опять срабатывает `$(document).mouseup()`, но `container` уже инициализируется. У него удаляется класс `container.removeClass("show");`, после этого в `$(".btn").on("click")` класс добавляется опять.

Вариант решения не вызывать обработчик `onmuseup` для кнопки. Или сделать общий клик

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('btn'))
    $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
  else
    $(".menu").removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  position: absolute;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu" class="menu">
  <a href="">.item1</a>
  <a href="">.item2</a>
  <a href="">.item3</a>
  <a href="">.item4</a>
  <a href="">.item5</a>
  <a href="">.item6</a>
</div>

<div class="btn">
  button
</div>
```